# mediaelement.js changeSkin

Tags: jquery, css, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

Even though it does not have much documentation I can find on the subject I know that in mediaelement.js you can change the skin of the audio player or modify the CSS to create your own skin. I am running into a problem where I can't even get the default mediaelement.js skin to replace the browser player therefore I can't modify the default CSS to my styling needs. And when I try to use the player.changeSkin() method which mediaelement.js uses on their site it halts the program. I am including the skin CSS as well as the other required mediaelement.js files, at least to the best of my knowledge, and they player works fine until I try to change the skin. I am using this code to stream audio and you can find a working version (last working upload before trying to skin the player) at http://escapetodenton.com/radio/compact-player.html. For some reason the player itself is not rendering at all right now in my version of firefox either so if you have chrome or ie you'll get a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Imported files in the header:

```
<script src="build/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="build/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/mediaelementplayer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="build/mejs-skins.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"src="http://premiumca5.listen2myradio.com/system/streaminfo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="compact-player.css" />
```

Player instantiation and launch:

```
var player = new MediaElement('player', {
pluginPath: '/build/',
features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','volume'],
audioWidth: 400,
enableAutosize: false,
iPadUseNativeControls: true,
iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
AndroidUseNativeControls: true,
success: function(player, node) {
player.changeSkin('mejs-ted');
player.play();
}
});
```

Since I can't find any documentation on the changeSkin() method I am just using it in the same way that mediaelement.js has it in their code for their home page. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I spent some time with mediaelement.js a while ago. As far as I remember, I found all of the CSS and just pinned down what was what and styled it. The problems that I ran into, was the fact that it has a flash fall back. (Which is great in theory) So you really have to re theme that too. It cant really be responsive. I tried to build some Ajax playlist functionality, but the flash fall back was such a problem that I abandoned the whole thing. I remember there being 3 or four "skins" available. Those might shed light on what CSS you'll need to write.

Comment: I was finally able to change enough of the default skin to please the client and get it to render fairly seamlessly on all major browsers (falling back to solid black, no gradient on older versions of ie) I am using Ajax to change station streams which is working in both hmtl5 versions and the flash fallback. If you'd like to see that implementation I'd be happy to share my code. It definitely took me some time to get it working consistently. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Create jsfiddle version of your code and maybe we can play with it a little bit.

Comment: I have created my own skin in the past and it worked fine. I doubt that you can change skin by using any JavaScript methods of mediaelementjs but I think it is possible to find another solution for you. But first make a jsfiddle.

Comment: There is a changeSkin() method in the mediaelement.js library which swaps out classes, however I just ended up using some modifications to the mediaelement.css standard skins on the live site. Here is a fiddle using Ajax to change streaming stations on the fly. http://jsfiddle.net/jdbosley/Nx7dt/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is add `class="mejs-ted"` on your video element. The changeSkin() function is afaik used for dynamically swapping skins. Ie: you want to provide multiple skins that a user can switch between.

So your video tag should have your class added to it, and will look something like this:

```
<!-- replace mejs-ted with mejs-yourclass -->
<video class="mejs-ted" ...>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="....">
    <source type="video/ogg" src="....">
    <!-- etc.. -->
</video>
```

Mediaelement automatically checks for the class attribute on the video element, and adds that class to the parent container so all DOM elements can be overridden through prefixing with .mejs-yourclass

If you just want to change the default skin setting the class works fine. The mejs-skins.css has example CSS for all the styles you need to override in order to skin it differently. The only thing missing is the styles for the bigplay button:

```
/* overlay bigplay */
.mejs-yourclass .mejs-overlay-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
    background: url(bigplay.png) no-repeat;
}

.mejs-yourclass .mejs-overlay:hover .mejs-overlay-button {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

You'll find working examples from git: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/blob/master/demo/mediaelementplayer-skins.html

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this article http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/03/custom-html5-video-player/ on InsertHTML should help you with your case.

It is using mediaelement.js to design custom CSS3 video players with HTML5 and JavaScript.